# Setting a textbox value by JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am setting a `TextBox` controls value via an ajax post.

```
$('#txtSite').val(msg.d.SiteName);
```

This is working and the value of the `TextBox` is altered correctly.  But, when I come to posting the information to the database, the `txtSite.Text` value is empty!!

Any ideas?  Am I going mad?

Code to populate the `TextBox`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "MyPage.aspx/ValidateSite",
    data: "{ siteID: '" + $('#txtSiteID').val() + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg.d != null) {
            $('#txtSite').val(msg.d.SiteName);  // It's definitely doing this
        }
        else {
            $('#txtSite').val('');
        }
    },
    error: function(msg) {
    }
});
```

Code to save to the server (all connectivity etc. is correct and working).  This code is in an ASP button click event:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Sites] ([SiteName]) VALUES ('" + txtSite.Text + "')", conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The `TextBox` is defined like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSite" runat="server" AutoComplete="off" TabIndex="4" MaxLength="50" Style="width: 230px" Enabled="false" CssClass="FormDisabledTextWithSmallHeight" />
```

I have also tried changing my JQuery to use plain Javascript instead and doing this:

```
document.getElementById("txtSite").value = msg.d.SiteName;
```

Still returns me an empty value.

Comment: Does `#txtSite` have a `name` attribute?

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, does it need a name attribute?  I have an `ID` for it.  Will give that a try.

Comment: @NeilKnight: When forms are submitted, it's the `name` and `value` that are submitted.

Comment: Added a `name` and it still fails.

Comment: If msg.d.SiteName is not null then try $("#<%=txtSite.ClientID%>").val(name)

Comment: @kad1r: It's not the JQuery that I'm posting from. The JQuery post gets the values from the database and populates the textbox.  It is populating the textbox correctly, but when I save the data using CSharp code, the `TextBox.Text` property is empty.

Comment: If your textbox has the ID of `txtSite`, then you should be referencing it with the same ID in ASP.NET, shouldn't you? I.E. `txtSite.Text`

Comment: Which is what I am doing, but the value of it is empty.

Comment: You said you are doing `TextBox.Text`. Show us all of your code.

Comment: Erm, wait, the code you posted is not relevant. Show us the code that submits the form. I suspect this is an issue with the VIEWSTATE not getting returned to the server.

Comment: @crush: it doesn't matter what `TextBox` I assign the value to from the JQuery.  Whichever one I use they all return empty values when I try to insert the data into the database.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your form html..I have a feeling there's something missing there, but we won't know until you share the  full form html too.

Comment: Can you provide `ValidateSite`?

Comment: `ValidateSite` is a `SELECT` statement.  It's not important as that part is working fine.  It's the part where I submit the form that it is failing.

Comment: Is the textbox in a disabled state by any chance?

Comment: Please provide the HTML as requested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have your textbox set to `Enabled="false"` which renders in the browser with a `disabled="disabled"`. **[Disabled form inputs are not submitted.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.disabled.aspx)**

The solution is either to make the textbox enabled and read-only:

```
txtSite.Enabled = true;
txtSite.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly"); //on prerender event or somewhere else
```

or to use a different element set with `runat="server"`, like a `<asp:HiddenField />` and update both the textbox and the alternate element with your AJAX call:

```
success: function(msg) {
    if (msg.d != null) {
        $('#txtSite').val(msg.d.SiteName);
        $('#hiddenInput').val(msg.d.SiteName);
    } else {
            $('#txtSite').val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try with setting the field to `ReadOnly` but that still failed.  I implemented the `HiddenField` solution yesterday morning as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I definitely think, your text box should have a name attribute in html code, check for it. Without a 'name' attribute browser won't post this input box's data to server and thus you won't get it in server side c# code. Hope, this make sense..

Comment: hmm. I will request you to share your .aspx file code(which part is main concern) along with the backend c# code full function, so that we can review in a good way. Thanks.