# Set value to textbox control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to Set value of age into Textbox id is txtage? 
I want to set age into textbox value instead of alert box

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server" />
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="imgPopup" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar.png" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" OnClientDateSelectionChanged="DateSelectionChanged"
        runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DateSelectionChanged(e) {
            var today = new Date();
            var dob = e.get_selectedDate();
            var months = (today.getMonth() - dob.getMonth() + (12 * (today.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear())));
            alert("Your age: " + Math.round(months / 12));
        }    
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do here?

Comment: do `$("#"+ "<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").val("your value")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a textbox value by JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484168/setting-a-textbox-value-by-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```
$('#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>').val("your value");
```

In **asp.net** use the client ID - recommended but meh.. not so much. I would try to avoid writing **ClientID** in javascript as much as possible.

Comment: @UrvishPatel can i get my credits? If it helps make it as answer. and do upvote

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
using jquery

```
$('[id$=txtDate]').val('your value');
```

or using javascript

```
document.getElementById('txtDate').value='your value';
```